# Asserting if a NameValueCollection is equivalent

Tags: c#, nunit

Does anyone know of a good way to assert if a NameValueCollection is equivalent? At the moment I'm using NUnit, but CollectionAssert.AreEquivalent() seems to only assert the keys. Not the keys and the values.

I wrote this little piece of code to help me out, but it would be nice if there was something out-of-the-box that could do the same.

```
private static void AssertNameValueCollectionAreEquivalent(NameValueCollection expectedCollection, NameValueCollection collection)
{
   // Will evaluate keys only
   CollectionAssert.AreEquivalent(expectedCollection, collection);

   foreach (string namevalue in collection)
   {
      Assert.AreEqual(expectedCollection[namevalue], collection[namevalue]);
   }
}
```

Comment: You should at least change the *name* of your method - you can't just assert a collection. You have to assert something *about* the collection - in this case, its equivalence with an expected collection. (This was confusing me in the text before your code, too.)

Comment: Changed method name and updated text and title to better reflect my question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

how about convert it to Dictionary and assert as:

```
CollectionAssert.AreEquivalent(
    expectedCollection.AllKeys.ToDictionary(k => k, k => expectedCollection[k]),
    collection.AllKeys.ToDictionary(k => k, k => collection[k]));
```

Comment: Works like a charm! :)
Although it's quite much to write. But if you can't use the solution HackedByChinese suggested I think this is ok.

Comment: I have to add that this works a lot better than my code sample above since it is a lot easier to actually see where the difference is in the values. Thanks again!

Answer (score 2):

I am a fan of `Fluent Assertions` for NUnit. not only is the syntax fluent and more concise, but they make a number of assertions easier, and this is one of them.

Consider:

```
var c = new NameValueCollection();
var c2 = new NameValueCollection();

c.Add("test1", "testvalue1");
c.Add("test2", "testvalue2");

c2.Add("test1", "testvalue1");
c2.Add("test2", "testvalue2");

c.Should().BeEquivalentTo(c2); // assertion succeeds
```

Comment: That looks nice, but Should() isn't part of regular NUnit or am I mistaken?

Comment: `Should` is part of Fluent Assertions, which you can download from NuGet or here: http://fluentassertions.codeplex.com

Comment: Nice! I will definitely check it out, not sure it's OK to use in this project though. But thanks for the tip. :)

Comment: The above example is broken, it only checks the keys and not the values:

`var c1 = new NameValueCollection(); var c2 = new NameValueCollection(); c1.Add("test1", "testvalue1"); c1.Add("test2", "testvalue2"); c2.Add("test1", "broken"); c2.Add("test2", "useless"); c1.Should().BeEquivalentTo(c2); // assertion succeeds`

Comment: Just a side note, flaw with this approach is that it expects both actual and expceted to have same datatype (in this case, NameValueCollection).  If datatypes are different, none of these will work.